# How to call Postgres function using express.js pg.Pool

Tags: javascript, postgresql, express

I have the following code written. I am not sure if it works but basically am trying to create a function that inserts a new todo with a description unless that description is `bad todo`. Obviously this is just for testing but I want to call this function I created in my express app.

```
BEGIN;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION perntodo.createTodo(
  description perntodo.todoDescription%Type)

RETURNS VARCHAR AS
$$
DECLARE
BEGIN
  IF description == 'bad todo' THEN
    RAISE EXCEPTION 'Cannot post this todo!';
  ELSE
    INSERT INTO TODO VALUES(description);
  END IF;
END;

COMMIT;
```

My controller looks like this...

```
router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { description } = req.body;
    // const newTodo = await pool.query(
    //   'INSERT INTO todo (description) VALUES($1) RETURNING *',
    //   [description]
    // );

    const newTodo = await pool.func('perntodo.createTodo', [description]);

    res.json(newTodo.rows[0]);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
    res.status(500).send('Server Error...');
  }
});
```

The commented out code works. But the `pool.func` says it's not a function. What am I doing wrong.

This is how I connected to my database

```
const Pool = require('pg').Pool;
const user = './user';
const DBPASSWORD = './pass';

const pool = new Pool({
  user: user,
  password: DBPASSWORD,
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 5432,
  database: 'perntodo',
});

module.exports = pool;
```

Comment: Where did you get `pool.func` from? Documentation somewhere?

Comment: I don't remember where I found it but no I did not see it in the docs. The only thing I found was after establishing a db connection I saw others calling their psql function using `db.func`. `Pool` may not be what I want to use, but I'm having a tough time figuring out what it is I need.

Comment: Others using `db.func` where? I think it’s something like `pool.query('CALL perntodo.createTodo($1)', [description])`.

Comment: @Ry- `createTodo` is a function, [not a procedure](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-call.html), so `SELECT perntodo.createTodo($1);` it is.

Comment: You might have been using [pg-promise's `.func` method](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/Database.html#func)? node-postgres only [features `.query`](https://node-postgres.com/features/queries/).

Comment: Thank you all for your comments, doing `CALL` with `pool.query` worked. Although, that is not where I saw the `.func` being used I do think that is what I was doing and was not working. I figured out after seeing @Ry- do `CALL` that I needed a procedure. Again, thanks everyone for the help!